# Why is this creating a black image?

Tags: php

In the images folder i have a notfound.php file with

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');
    $im = imagecreatefrompng('simnotfound.png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
    ?>
```

The image is a 256 by 256. The notfound.php page shows a black 256 by 256 square. The image is not all black tho. Its just some black text on a transparent background in the center.

The fix is

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');
    $im = imagecreatefrompng('simnotfound.png');
    imagealphablending($im, true); // setting alpha blending on
    imagesavealpha($im, true); // save alphablending setting (important)
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
    ?>
```

Comment: If it's transparent, what are you expecting the background colour to appear as? What browsers have you tested this on? Can we get an URL?

Comment: the content of `simnotfound.png`?

Comment: Nvm found a fix. imagealphablending and imagesavealpha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create your image file one more time with white background to check that is read correctly, if yes - problem is your transparent background

also try with other file to eliminate problem with reading this specific file

Comment: Seems like its the transparency then. White image back ground shows up fine.

Comment: Thanks for telling me to make the background white. It helped me troubleshoot the issue. Googled it and found the fix.

Comment: @keverw that is cool that you found the solution but it would be even cooler if you shared it by updating your question with the solution link or pice of code that solved your problem for further reference to others ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
bool imagesavealpha ( resource $image , bool $saveflag )
```

imagesavealpha — Set the flag to save full alpha channel information (as opposed to single-color transparency) when saving PNG images